# Excel: How to weeknumbers in number formatting

Tags: excel, number-formatting

I would like to use weeknumbers in number formatting in Excel, in particular in XY-graphs.

The built-in function WEEKNUM() can be used to extract the weeknumber from a date. With these weeknumbers I can proceed in two different manners:

- use the weeknumbers as text labels on my graph axis. This does not give the required result as labels are distributed evenly on the axis. A sequence like "13" "14" "33" would put the label "14" just in the middle.
- use the weeknumbers as numbers on my graphs axis. This would resolve the above problem, but gives a gap at years end. E.g. 1652 (week 52 in 2016) and 1701 are 49 units away from each other.

To illustrate, please see these two graphs. The graphs indicate a tracking of a project plan, i.e. planned versus actuals. The first chart is a correct graph somewhere in the midst of a year; the second chart is more or less the same graph crossing year's end.

[Correct chart, in the midst of a year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCW3Y.png)

[Chart showing problem at year's end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZOQt.png)

Now I'm stuck. My preferred route would be to add a number format to the generic number formatting methods in Excel. E.g. similar to be able to use yyyy for years and ddd for days, I'd like to use ww for weeknumbers.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I use similar charts with week along X axis and I do not have the problem you state. Can you post a screenshot of your chart?

Comment: Oh, I understood the problem now.

Comment: An option will be to introduce zero values for the missing weeks. Alternately you can replace the week number with a date (say Monday of the week) and format the axis as date (in case automatic recognition of date does not work).

Answer (score 0):

Not certain I'm understanding the question fully, but if you're wanting to ensure the end result is treated as a number you could use =Text(WEEKNUM(A1), "#") which would convert it to a numeric value.

For the chart, sounds like you could use the axis options (right click on the axis labels >> Format Axis).  There are multiple options that would allow you to change how the labels are displayed.

Comment: My question could be answered if there is a way to slide in my own formatting formula's as an option to format the axis. How would I add a new label, e.g. "ww", and add some Excel or VBS formula underneath?